# What JS runtimes can TypeScript potentially run on?

Tags: typescript

...apart from Node.js and Windows Script Host, which are both supported by Microsoft.

Did anybody try to run in over IronJS or *Monkey, Rhino, Carakan, Microsoft.JScript etc.?

**Update:** apparently, there's a fork [supporting Rhino](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/nobuoka/TypeScript/changeset/view/c2417dec616e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other hosts aren't going to work out of the box because there's no file I/O implementation in `io.ts`, unless those hosts happen to have file APIs that exactly match node or WSH's.

Comment: I'm wondering about 'potential'. Apparently, there's a branch to run on Rhino -- just found out (will update the question). But it's useful to know what other engines it's compatible with.

Comment: I think 'potentially' it's any JavaScript host. If the compiler is emitting WSH- or V8-specific code, that'd be considered a bug.

Comment: Actually, Microsoft.JScript (included in .NET) doesn't seem to like it because of keyword clash at least (get/set).

Answer (score 3):

There have been several approaches to run the TypeScript compiler in a Java environment. Besides the above mentioned "maven-typescript-plugin" (seems to be abandoned btw.) there is also a project called "Typescript4j".

But as far as I have found out, running TypeScript on Java's Rhino JS engine has a huge performance issue in general: Due to a nasty JVM issue ("64K method size limit") it is not possible to run Rhino in an "optimized" but it needs to executed in the "interpretive" mode. As a consequence, parsing the internally bundled "lib.d.ts" (which is necessary for every TypeScript compiler execution) takes a very long time (at least 30s on my computer!). I have also played around with the new Nashorn JS engine (to be bundled with JDK 8) but I haven't noticed a performance improvement.

In the end, I'm using the "grunt-maven-plugin" for compiling TypeScript files in a Java/Maven project. You might want to have a look at http://pegirino.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/typescript-in-maven-projects/ and/or https://github.com/pkaul/maven-typescript-example for more detailed description and an example.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fork you've mentioned it's certainly possible to implement your own adapter for pretty much any runtime, for an example see https://github.com/ppedregal/typescript-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/modules/fs.js.